# How can I find all the subsets of a set, with exactly n elements?

Tags: python

I am writing a program in Python, and I realized that a problem I need to solve requires me, given a set `S` with `n` elements (|S|=n), to test a function on all possible subsets of a certain order `m` (i.e. with *m* number of elements). To use the answer to produce a partial solution, and then try again with the next order m=m+1, until m=n.

I am on my way to write a solution of the form:

```
def findsubsets(S, m):
    subsets = set([])
    ...
    return subsets
```

But knowing Python I expected a solution to be already there.

What is the best way to accomplish this?

Comment: `scipy.misc.comb(S, m)` gives the number of subsets you will get. You should eventually make a check before you execute your code as the number of m-sized subsets of S gets very big very fast.

Comment: Literally had the same problem, set out to code it myself and then realized that there must exist a Python library for this!

Answer (score 137, accepted):

[itertools.combinations](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations) is your friend if you have Python 2.6 or greater.  Otherwise, check the link for an implementation of an equivalent function.

```
import itertools
def findsubsets(S,m):
    return set(itertools.combinations(S, m))
```

S: The set for which you want to find subsets
m: The number of elements in the subset

Comment: i would not return a set, but simply return the iterator (or just use combinations() without defining a findsubsets()...)

Comment: @hop the OP particularly asked for sets. Omitting the set cast allows repetitions in different orders, eg: (1,2,3), (2,3,1), (3,1,2)...

Comment: @JamesBradbury: I'm sorry, I don't understand what you mean. Are you confusing this with permutations?

Answer (score 64):

Using the canonical function to get the [powerset](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_set) from the [the itertools recipe](https://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#recipes) page:

```
from itertools import chain, combinations

def powerset(iterable):
    """
    powerset([1,2,3]) --> () (1,) (2,) (3,) (1,2) (1,3) (2,3) (1,2,3)
    """
    xs = list(iterable)
    # note we return an iterator rather than a list
    return chain.from_iterable(combinations(xs,n) for n in range(len(xs)+1))
```

Used like:

```
>>> list(powerset("abc"))
[(), ('a',), ('b',), ('c',), ('a', 'b'), ('a', 'c'), ('b', 'c'), ('a', 'b', 'c')]

>>> list(powerset(set([1,2,3])))
[(), (1,), (2,), (3,), (1, 2), (1, 3), (2, 3), (1, 2, 3)]
```

map to sets if you want so you can use union, intersection, etc...:

```
>>> map(set, powerset(set([1,2,3])))
[set([]), set([1]), set([2]), set([3]), set([1, 2]), set([1, 3]), set([2, 3]), set([1, 2, 3])]

>>> reduce(lambda x,y: x.union(y), map(set, powerset(set([1,2,3]))))
set([1, 2, 3])
```

Answer (score 26):

Here's a function that gives you all subsets of the integers [0..n], not just the subsets of a given length:

```
from itertools import combinations, chain

def allsubsets(n):
    return list(chain(*[combinations(range(n), ni) for ni in range(n+1)]))
```

so e.g.

```
>>> allsubsets(3)
[(), (0,), (1,), (2,), (0, 1), (0, 2), (1, 2), (0, 1, 2)]
```

Comment: Useful formula, but use `chain.from_iterable` instead of star-expanding a potentially very long set. And what's the point of iterating the combinations into a list (`[ ... ]`), star-expanding, chaining into an iterator (`chain`), and then turning into a list _again_? PS. a better recipe is in the `itertools` documentation, and in another (later) answer here.

Comment: Named lambdas are bad practice. Use a `def` instead.

Comment: @wjandrea it is a one-liner.

Comment: @Kowalski what do you mean?

Comment: @Kowalski Yes, of course it was a one-liner. What do you mean?

Comment: @wjandrea nevermind, IMHO it is not always bad to use named lambdas.

Answer (score 5):

Here is one neat way with easy to understand algorithm.

```py
import copy

nums = [2,3,4,5]
subsets = [[]]

for n in nums:
    prev = copy.deepcopy(subsets)
    [k.append(n) for k in subsets]
    subsets.extend(prev)

print(subsets) 
print(len(subsets))

# [[2, 3, 4, 5], [3, 4, 5], [2, 4, 5], [4, 5], [2, 3, 5], [3, 5], [2, 5], [5], 
# [2, 3, 4], [3, 4], [2, 4], [4], [2, 3], [3], [2], []]

# 16 (2^len(nums))
```

Comment: It should be `k.append(n)` instead of `k.extend(n)`

Answer (score 4):

Here's some pseudocode - you can cut same recursive calls by storing the values for each call as you go and before recursive call checking if the call value is already present.

The following algorithm will have all the subsets excluding the empty set.

```
list * subsets(string s, list * v) {

    if(s.length() == 1) {
        list.add(s);    
        return v;
    }
    else
    {
        list * temp = subsets(s[1 to length-1], v);
        int length = temp->size();

        for(int i=0;i<length;i++) {
            temp.add(s[0]+temp[i]);
        }

        list.add(s[0]);
        return temp;
    }
}
```

So, for example if s = "123" then output is:

```
1
2
3
12
13
23
123
```

Answer (score 3):

**Without using `itertools`**:

In Python 3 you can use `yield from` to add a subset generator method to buit-in `set` class:

```
class SetWithSubset(set):
    def subsets(self):
        s1 = []
        s2 = list(self)

        def recfunc(i=0):            
            if i == len(s2):
                yield frozenset(s1)
            else:                
                yield from recfunc(i + 1)
                s1.append(s2[ i ])
                yield from recfunc(i + 1)
                s1.pop()

        yield from recfunc()
```

For example below snippet works as expected:

```
x = SetWithSubset({1,2,3,5,6})
{2,3} in x.subsets()            # True
set() in x.subsets()            # True
x in x.subsets()                # True
x|{7} in x.subsets()            # False
set([5,3]) in x.subsets()       # True - better alternative: set([5,3]) < x
len(x.subsets())                # 32
```

Comment: great use of `yield from` and with an algorithmic explanation

Answer (score 0):

`$ python -c "import itertools; a=[2,3,5,7,11]; print sum([list(itertools.combinations(a, i)) for i in range(len(a)+1)], [])"
[(), (2,), (3,), (5,), (7,), (11,), (2, 3), (2, 5), (2, 7), (2, 11), (3, 5), (3, 7), (3, 11), (5, 7), (5, 11), (7, 11), (2, 3, 5), (2, 3, 7), (2, 3, 11), (2, 5, 7), (2, 5, 11), (2, 7, 11), (3, 5, 7), (3, 5, 11), (3, 7, 11), (5, 7, 11), (2, 3, 5, 7), (2, 3, 5, 11), (2, 3, 7, 11), (2, 5, 7, 11), (3, 5, 7, 11), (2, 3, 5, 7, 11)]`

Answer (score 0):

```
>>>Set = ["A", "B","C","D"]
>>>n = 2
>>>Subsets=[[i for i,s in zip(Set, status) if int(s)  ] for status in [(format(bit,'b').zfill(len(Set))) for bit in range(2**len(Set))] if sum(map(int,status)) == n]
>>>Subsets
[['C', 'D'], ['B', 'D'], ['B', 'C'], ['A', 'D'], ['A', 'C'], ['A', 'B']]
```

Comment: do explain why that'd do what is asked for.

Comment: Just try it and you'll see if it'd do what it asked for

Answer (score 0):

Another solution using recursion:

```
def subsets(nums: List[int]) -> List[List[int]]:
    n = len(nums)
    output = [[]]
    
    for num in nums:
        output += [curr + [num] for curr in output]
    
    return output
```

Starting from empty subset in output list. At each step we take a new integer into consideration and generates new subsets from the existing ones.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an implementation using simple recursion from first principles.
Base case: if there are no elements then return the empty set.
Recursive case: choose an element and return all subsets of the other elements
with and without the chosen element added.

```py
def _all_subsets(s):
    seq = list(s)
    if not seq:
        yield set([])
    else:
        choice = set([seq[0]])
        others = seq[1:]
        for without_choice in _all_subsets(others):
            yield without_choice
            yield choice | without_choice

def all_subsets(iterable):
    s = set(iterable)
    for x in _all_subsets(s):
        yield x
```