# Perform "count" in all subsets of a set of columns

Tags: python, dataframe, count, subset

Having a dataframe, 'df':

```
l = [['a',1,3,3,1,1,3,3,3],['b',1,1,3,1,3,3,1,3],['c',1,1,1,1,3,1,1,1]]
col = ['id','x1','x2','x3','x4','y1','y2','y3','y4']

df = pd.DataFrame (l, columns = col)
```

[image: df]

I want to count the number of rows (ids) with value "1" in each subset of subsets of X= {x1,x2,x3,x4} and Y = {y1,y2,y3,y4} columns. 
For an example subset s1={ [x1,x3] , [y2,y3,y4] }, the code does:

```
df[(df['x1']==1) & (df['x3']==1) & (df['y2'] == 1) & (df['y3'] == 1) & (df['y4'] == 1)].count()['id']
```

and return "1" as count. And repeat this for all subsets of {subsets of X columns} x {subsets of Y columns}.

I need to first construct all subsets of subsets (using for example the function suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/374626/how-can-i-find-all-the-subsets-of-a-set-with-exactly-n-elements)), and then perform the counts for each subset. What is the best way to perform this?

Comment: Do you mean literally all subsets, of all sizes?

Comment: Yes,all subsets of all sizes! :-)