# Find unique groups of subsets of a list in python

Tags: python, set

I have a list , `guys = range(1,21)`
and have gotten the unique combination of pairs using

```
itertools.combinations(guys,2)
```

I'm looking to create 19 sets using these subset pairs such that each value is listed only once in each set.

For example, the first set would be:

```
(1,2),(3,4),(5,6),(7,8),(9,10),(11,12),(13,14),(15,16),(17,18),(19,20)
```

And the following 18 sets would be similar, a unique set with 10 of these combination pairs where each number is only used once.

For example, if this were for `range(4)`, the total answer would be:

```
[(0,1),(2,3)], [(0,2),(1,3)], [(0,3),(1,2)]
```

I don't really even know where to begin.

Comment: So you want to generate the set of partitions into pairs of some set (in this case a range from 1..21)?

Comment: "… such that each value is listed only once in each set." In a **set** all item are listed only once.

Comment: Right, my wording was wrong. I meant, for example, the set (4,5) and (4,10) wouldn't be in the same set. The two are unique sets, but both include 4.

Comment: @KlausD. In this case I think he means a set of pairs, i.e. some subset of the power set.

Comment: Can you set yourself a simpler problem to start? Suppose you had range(4): [0,1,2,3], and you wanted all of these sets of pairs. How many such sets are there? Can you do it on paper? How would you do it with range(5)?

Comment: Right, so using range(4), I'd have:
[(0,1),(2,3)], [(0,2),(1,3)], [(0,3),(1,2)].

@castle-bravo, I know you meant that as a hint/starting point. I'm just also including what I'm looking for as a means to explain my question a little better.

Comment: What about [(1,0), (3,2)]?

Comment: well no, because that would be the same as the first one. I am just looking for the combinations of each, not the permutations.

Comment: Okay, so given N numbers, how many ways are there to select a single pair from those N numbers?

Comment: I think there is a [duplicate question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/374626/how-can-i-find-all-the-subsets-of-a-set-with-exactly-n-elements).

Comment: Yes, that may what I'm looking for