# Python 3 - Reducing a list by cyclical reconstructing a given set

Tags: python, python-3.x, algorithm, sorting

I am looking for an algorithm that reduces a list of tuples cyclical by reconstructing a given set as pattern.

Each tuple contains an id and a set, like `(1, {'xy'})`.

**Example**

```
query = {'xyz'}

my_dict = [(1, {'x'}), (2, {'yx'}), (3, {'yz'}),
           (4, {'z'}), (5, {'x'}), (6, {'y'}), 
           (7, {'xyz'}), (8, {'xy'}), (9, {'x'}),]
```

The goal is to recreate the pattern `xyz` as often as possible given the second value of the tuples in `my_dict`. Remaining elements from which the query set can not be completely reconstructed shall be cut off, hence 'reduce'.

`my_dict` contains in total: 6 times `x`, 5 times `y`, 3 times `z`.

Considering the `my_dict`, valid solutions would be for example:

```
result_1 = [(7, {'xyz'}), (8, {'xy'}), (4, {'z'}), (1, {'x'}), (3, {'yz'})]
result_2 = [(7, {'xyz'}), (2, {'yx'}), (4, {'z'}), (1, {'x'}), (3, {'yz'})]
result_3 = [(7, {'xyz'}), (9, {'x'}), (6, {'y'}), (4, {'z'}), (1, {'x'}), (3, {'yz'})]
```

The order of the tuples in the list is NOT important, i sorted them in the order of the query pattern `xyz` for the purpose of illustration.

**Goal**

The goal is to have a list of tuples where the total number of occurrences of the elements from the query set is most optimal evenly distributed.

`result_1`, `result_2` and `result_3` all contain in total: 3 times `x`, 3 times `y`, 3 times `z`.

Does anyone know a way/ approach how to do this?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on your application context, a naive brute-force approach might be enough: using the `powerset` function from [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16915734/857390),

```
def find_solutions(query, supply):
    for subset in powerset(supply):   
        if is_solution(query, subset):
            yield subset
```

You would need to implement a function `is_solution(query, subset)` that returns `True` when the given subset of the supply (`my_dict.values()`) is a valid solution for the given query.