# Generate the partition of a set

Tags: python, python-3.x, algorithm, combinatorics

Given a string like `xyz` i would like to generate the [partition of a set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_of_a_set).
NOT a power set but only pairings one can construct the original string from (see example below).

```
def get_pairings(a_string):
    # return a list of lists where each list contains 
    # lists that together contain all the characters of a_string
```

**Example**

Given the string `xyz`, the function `get_pairings` shall return:

```
[
 [['x'], ['y'], ['z']], 
 [['z'], ['x', 'y']], 
 [['x'], ['y', 'z']], 
 [['y'], ['x', 'z']],
 [['x', 'y', 'z']]
]
```

Given the string `xy`, the result would be:

```
[
 [['x'], ['y']],
 [['x', 'y']]
]
```

How is this possible in python?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: No i don't mean a power set. I am only looking for pairings that all together construct the original string.

Comment: Your example, demostrates a power set.

Comment: How do you want duplicates to be handled? If the string is `xxy`, should there be two items in the result set that are `[['x'], ['x', 'y']]`?

Comment: @SamerTufail No, it doesn't. `{{}, {x}, {y}, {z}, {x, y}, {x, z}, {y, z}, {x, y, z}}` is the power set which is nowhere near what the OP wants.

Comment: The difference between a straight up powerset and what OP wants is the outputs are joined in a way that inside the list they can create the input. There is a slight difference.

Comment: No, the power set of `xyz` would be: `{{}, {x}, {y}, {z}, {x, y}, {x, z}, {y, z}, {x, y, z}}`. I am looking for all possible pairings of `xyz` to construct `xyz`.

Comment: @Ixop the most inner list which contains the characters should be treated as a set. So order does not matter and no duplicates.

Comment: What you are looking for is a list of all  ["set partitions"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_of_a_set) of your initial pool.

Comment: Yes, blind me, misunderstood.

Comment: @schwobaseggl YES, set partitions, that's it!

Comment: You just asked [a very similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50925906/857390). Please do not multi-post.