# Combinations of lists within lists

Tags: python, combinations

Working through a combinations problem and attempting to output a list with a list of lists as input.  Closest solution that I've found is here: [All combinations of a list of lists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/798854/all-combinations-of-a-list-of-lists)

However, I do not want all combinations between lists, but within each list.  For example

```
[[1],[2,3],[4,5,6]] -> [[1],[2],[3],[2,3],[4],[5],[6],[4,5],[4,6],            
[5,6],[4,5,6]]
```

Comment: How deep can this list be? Will it only ever be a list of lists? Also, does the order of the output list matter?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Credit to [How can I find all the subsets of a set, with exactly n elements?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16915734/8150685)

First find a way to find all subsets for one list (also called the power set):

```
from itertools import chain, combinations

def powerset(iterable):
    """
    powerset([1,2,3]) --> [[1], [2], [3], [1, 2], [1, 3], [2, 3], [1, 2, 3]]
    """
    xs = list(iterable)
    return [list(x) for x in chain.from_iterable(combinations(xs,n) for n in range(len(xs)+1)) if x]
```

Then iterate for each list:

```
list_of_list = [[1],[2,3],[4,5,6]]
result = []
for x in list_of_list:
    result += powerset(x)
print(result)
```

**Output:**

```
[[1], [2], [3], [2, 3], [4], [5], [6], [4, 5], [4, 6], [5, 6], [4, 5, 6]]
```

Comment: Nice...does exactly what I need it to do.  Appreciate it

Answer (score 1):

Below, I define a helper function to get all of the combinations from a sequence, then apply that to every sublist of your input list and [`chain`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain.from_iterable) the results together.

```
from itertools import chain, combinations

l=[[1],[2,3],[4,5,6]]

def all_comb(seq):
    return chain.from_iterable(combinations(seq, i) for i in range(1, len(seq)+1))

print(list(chain.from_iterable(map(all_comb, l))))
# [(1,), (2,), (3,), (2, 3), (4,), (5,), (6,), (4, 5), (4, 6), (5, 6), (4, 5, 6)]
```

Answer (score 0):

with `itertools.combinations`:

```
from itertools import combinations

l = [[1],[2,3],[4,5,6]]

combos = sum([[list(c) for c in combinations(x, i)] for x in l for i in range(1, len(x)+1)], [])

combos
>>> [[1], [2], [3], [2, 3], [4], [5], [6], [4, 5], [4, 6], [5, 6], [4, 5, 6]]
```