# Python get all comination of sub-sampling from list

Tags: python, list, iteration, combinations, python-itertools

I have two list:
A with the size of 49 and B with the size of 68.

I want to iterate over all possible subsamples in the size of 32 in the lists.

What is the best way to do it in python?

Comment: Be more specific.

Comment: Read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/374626/how-can-i-find-all-the-subsets-of-a-set-with-exactly-n-elements)

Comment: You have 49 elements in A, 68 in B, and want every possible sample? Like a0b0, a0b1, ..., a0b67, a1b0 and so on? And what about `32` anyway?

Comment: @crissal No, it should be not repititions. a0b0, a1b5, a2b1, a9b6, ...

Comment: I hope you've plenty of time, it's going to take a while to loop over all that

Comment: So you want N tuples made with 32 elements from A (first position) and 32 elements from B (second position) without repetitions?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `combinations` method of `itertools`.
Just you can change `items` data and the number of count in `combinations` method from `2` to `32`.
Please refer the following sample code:

```
from itertools import combinations

items_a = ['a', 'b', 'c']
items_b = ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5']
items = items_a + items_b

print(list(combinations(items_a, 2)))
print(list(combinations(items_b, 2)))
```

The result.

```
[('a', 'b'), ('a', 'c'), ('b', 'c')]
[('1', '2'), ('1', '3'), ('1', '4'), ('1', '5'), ('2', '3'), ('2', '4'), ('2', '5'), ('3', '4'), ('3', '5'), ('4', '5')]
```

Comment: please notice that the output should be 32 elements from list A and 32 elements from list B

Comment: @what do you mean?

Comment: @okuoub Please provide your sample data. And Please share your code snippet if you have.

Answer (score 0):

You don't want to do that.

You have two lists of size 48 and 68. You want size 32 subsets of each.

There are 2 e 12 and 2 e 19 subsets of each. Multiplying then you get 4 e 31. That's a very big number.

So here's a rule of thumb. 10 ^ 9 is roughly the number of operations per second. 10 ^ 16 is 1 year... You don't want to think about  ^ 31.

Let's put it this way. The hashrate of the entire bitcoin network is about 70, 000, 000 trillion hashes per second. Or 2.2 e 27 per year. That's still short a few zeros.

Change your algorithm.